# How can I show that the policy function is non-decreasing?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Consider the following functional equation:
$$V(x)=\max_{y\in [0,f(x)]}[u(f(x)-y)+\beta V(y)]$$
where $u$ is continuous, strictly increasing, and strictly concave; the function $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, and $\beta\in (0,1)$. Let $g(x)$ be the decision rule associated with this functional equation:
$$V(x)=u[f(x)-g(x)]+\beta V[g(x)]$$
How can I show that $g$ is non-decreasing (if $x'>x$, then $g(x')\geq g(x)$)?

**Assume that $f$ and $u$ are not necessarily differentiable.**

Comment: Why do you think it is?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I honestly have no idea. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x'>x$. We'll show that $g(x')\geq g(x)$. Suppose that is not the case and we have $x'>x$ but $g(x')<g(x)$. Since $0\leq g(x') < g(x) \leq f(x)< f(x')$, $g(x')$ is feasible in case of $x$, and $g(x)$ is feasible in case of $x'$, consequently both of the following inequalities are true:
\begin{eqnarray*}V(x')=u(f(x')-g(x'))+\beta V(g(x')) &\geq & u(f(x')-g(x))+\beta V(g(x)) \\
V(x)=u(f(x)-g(x))+\beta V(g(x))&\geq & u(f(x)-g(x'))+\beta V(g(x'))\end{eqnarray*}

Adding them we get the following inequality:

$u(f(x')-g(x'))+\beta V(g(x'))+u(f(x)-g(x))+\beta V(g(x))\geq u(f(x')-g(x))+\beta V(g(x))+u(f(x)-g(x'))+\beta V(g(x'))$

which yields
$u(f(x')-g(x'))-u(f(x)-g(x'))\geq u(f(x')-g(x))-u(f(x)-g(x))$

which, by strict concavity of $u$, implies that
$g(x')\geq g(x)$ contradicting that $g(x') < g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that everything is smooth and that the optimal solution $g(x)$ is interior (in $]0, f(x)[$)

First you can show that the function $V$ is concave as the Bellman operator maps concave functions to concave functions.

Now assume that the solution $g(x)$ is interior. Then the first order condition (with respect to $y$) gives:
$$
-u'(f(x) - g(x)) + \beta V'(g(x)) = 0.
$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $x$ gives:
$$
-u''(f(x) - g(x))f'(x) + u''(f(x) - g(x))g'(x) + \beta V''(g(x)) g'(x) = 0,
$$
So:
$$
g'(x) = \frac{u''(f(x) - g(x))f'(x)}{u''(f(x) - g(x)) + \beta V''(g(x))}.
$$
Both numerator and denominator on the right side are negative, so $g'(x) > 0$.

Comment: Since $f$ is not assumed to be concave, it is not clear to me why the value function should be concave.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker yes indeed. One could probably change the state variable from $x$ to $f(x)$, then show that $V$ is concave in $f(x)$ and therefore $g$ is monotone in $f(x)$. As $f$ is monotone, $g$ will then also be increasing in $x$.

Comment: Good point, that might work.

Comment: what if $u$ and $f$ are not assumed to be ddifferentiable?